# Desktop student administration application

Tags: java, mvc, swing

I'm writing my first Java MVC application which should be a desktop student administration application with a Swing GUI.

DAO is already implemented: [Student administration application using a .csv file for persistence](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/25788/need-some-feedback-student-administration-application)

The application should provide a login form. After successful login there should be a different frame/window with different actions based upon each user role (student, professor...).

**Main.java**

```
package com.studentenverwaltung;

import com.studentenverwaltung.controller.UserController;
import com.studentenverwaltung.model.User;
import com.studentenverwaltung.view.UserView;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User user = new User();
        UserView userView = new UserView();
        UserController userController = new UserController(user, userView);
        userController.login();
    }
}
```

**User.java**

```
package com.studentenverwaltung.model;

import com.studentenverwaltung.controller.UserController;

public class User {
    private UserController userController;
    private String id;
    private String password;

    public UserController getUserController() {
        return this.userController;
    }

    public void setUserController(UserController userController) {
        this.userController = userController;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean checkPassword(String password) {
        if (this.password.equals(password)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**UserController.java**

```
package com.studentenverwaltung.controller;

import com.studentenverwaltung.helpers.UserCredentials;
import com.studentenverwaltung.model.User;
import com.studentenverwaltung.persistence.FileUserDAO;
import com.studentenverwaltung.persistence.UserDAO;
import com.studentenverwaltung.view.UserView;

public class UserController {
    private User user;
    private UserView userView;

    public UserController(User user, UserView userView) {
        this.user = user;
        this.userView = userView;
        this.user.setUserController(this);
        this.userView.setUserController(this);
    }

    public void login() {
        UserDAO userDAO = new FileUserDAO("Files/users.csv");
        UserCredentials userCredentials;

        userCredentials = this.userView.loginForm();

        while (userCredentials != null) {
            String id = userCredentials.getId();
            String password = userCredentials.getPassword();

            if (userDAO.getUser(id) != null
                    && userDAO.getUser(id).checkPassword(password)) {
                this.userView.successfullyLoggedIn();
                System.exit(0);
            }

            System.out.println("Try again!\n==========");
            userCredentials = this.userView.loginForm();
        }
    }
}
```

**UserView.java**

```
package com.studentenverwaltung.view;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import com.studentenverwaltung.controller.UserController;
import com.studentenverwaltung.helpers.UserCredentials;

public class UserView {
    private UserController userController;

    public UserController getUserController() {
        return this.userController;
    }

    public void setUserController(UserController userController) {
        this.userController = userController;
    }

    public UserCredentials loginForm() {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        try {
            System.out.println("Enter Id...");
            String id = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Enter Password...");
            String password = br.readLine();

            return new UserCredentials(id, password);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void successfullyLoggedIn() {
        System.out.println("You're successfully logged in...!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Main.java**

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User user = new User();
        UserView userView = new UserView();
        UserController userController = new UserController(user, userView);
        userController.login();
    }
}
```

Nice, short, and easy to understand: good job! :)

**User.java**

```
package com.studentenverwaltung.model;
```

Warning: I'm going to nit a lot about accessors: it's important to think about them and not blindly add a getter and a setter for every value.

```
import com.studentenverwaltung.controller.UserController;

public class User {
    private UserController userController;
```

In typical MVC, the model doesn't have to know about the controller: it's the other way around: the view and the controller know about the model. This allows you to test your model independently.

```
    private String id;
    private String password;
```

I understand this is just an assignment, but consider hashing your password.

```
    public UserController getUserController() {
        return this.userController;
    }

    public void setUserController(UserController userController) {
        this.userController = userController;
    }
```

As said earlier, this is unnecessary (and unused!).

```
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

It's important to think about the accessors you provide. Do you really want to allow changing the id of a `User`?

```
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
```

Do you want to allow this? It's probably better to replase `setPassword()` by `resetPassword()`. And the only use case of `getPassword()` is covered by `checkPassword()`.

```
    public boolean checkPassword(String password) {
        if (this.password.equals(password)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

`checkPassword` is a good example of a nice getter: it doesn't simply return the value, but contains some logic. This kind of getter is what allows for encryption: you could hash the `password` paramater, and compare it to the real hashed password. Also note that tou can simply write `return this.password.equals(password);`.

**UserController.java**

```
import com.studentenverwaltung.persistence.FileUserDAO;
import com.studentenverwaltung.persistence.UserDAO;
```

Don't you think it's the model who should know about DAO?

```
import com.studentenverwaltung.view.UserView;

public class UserController {
    private User user;
    private UserView userView;

    public UserController(User user, UserView userView) {
        this.user = user;
        this.userView = userView;
        this.user.setUserController(this);
```

Makes sense: controller know about view and user.

```
        this.userView.setUserController(this);
```

This only makes sense if the view is a kind of GUI which can throw events at the controller. I don't think it's the case here.

```
    }

    public void login() {
        UserDAO userDAO = new FileUserDAO("Files/users.csv");
        UserCredentials userCredentials;

        userCredentials = this.userView.loginForm();

        while (userCredentials != null) {
```

In a typical MVC app, the controller doesn't poll the view: it's the view that sends events. However, since it's only a command-line app for now, this makes sense.

```
            String id = userCredentials.getId();
            String password = userCredentials.getPassword();

            if (userDAO.getUser(id) != null
                    && userDAO.getUser(id).checkPassword(password)) {
```

This should be in the model! MVC is all about fat models! :)

```
                this.userView.successfullyLoggedIn();
                System.exit(0);
            }

            System.out.println("Try again!\n==========");
            userCredentials = this.userView.loginForm();
        }
    }
}
```

**UserView.java**

```
import com.studentenverwaltung.controller.UserController;

public class UserView {
    private UserController userController;

    public UserController getUserController() {
        return this.userController;
    }

    public void setUserController(UserController userController) {
        this.userController = userController;
    }
```

All of this is unused here: in this command-line app, the view has no reason to know about the controller.

```
    public UserCredentials loginForm() {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        try {
            System.out.println("Enter Id...");
            String id = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Enter Password...");
            String password = br.readLine();

            return new UserCredentials(id, password);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void successfullyLoggedIn() {
        System.out.println("You're successfully logged in...!");
    }
```

Those last two methods make perfect sense.

I hope my comments helped you to better understand the way MVC works.

Comment: I agree with all of this, except for one point: _"Don't you think it's the model who should know about DAO?"_ I see the DAO as part of the model layer, and therefore, appropriate to access from a controller.

Comment: Thanks Quentin! The MVC Model you describe is the modified MVC Design like here: [Java SE Application Design With MVC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-142890.html)? So Controller knows about model and view, view knows about model and if we have a GUI view the view additionally knows about controller? And the view sends events to the controller?

By the way the setters are needed for the supercsv beanreader...

Comment: @Philipp indeed. Additionally, for a GUI view, the model sends events to the view so that it gets updated. (The other common MVC is the web one where the events are just requests, so you have less interactions.)

Comment: @Quentin Isn't that again the traditional MVC Design where you have Observer and Observable between Model and View compared to the modified MVC Design?

Comment: OK, I understood your previous question about the modified model. My answer doesn't specify which version it is since you have a dumb view. Now, with a GUI view, you can send events either via the controller ("modified version") or directly to the model ("old version"), that's up to you. Did I answer your question?